# Сhromatic number of a graph with a given decomposition

Tags: graph-theory

The original problem asks me to prove that if $G$ is a decomposition into graphs $H_1, H_2, \ldots, H_k$ where for each $i \in [k]$, $\chi(H_i) = c_i$, then $G$ is $c_1 \cdot c_2 \cdots \cdot c_k$-colorable. The approach I've been using to try to prove this thus far has been trying to prove the equivalent statement that $\chi(G) \leq c_1 \cdot c_2 \cdots\cdot c_k$. I have tried numerous strategies but have encountered roadblocks, I have tried proving it directly using propositions relating the chromatic number of $G$ to its maximum degree, but come short on those attempts as well as any attempts attacking contradiction. I would greatly appreciate any direction or a general outline of the proof strategy.

Comment: Proving it *directly* would not be using propositions relating chromatic number to maximum degree. Proving it directly - which you should absolutely try doing - means trying to give a rule that colors $G$ using $c_1 c_2 \cdots c_k$ colors, using the fact that every $H_i$ has a $c_i$-coloring.

Answer (score 0):

Hints.

1. Suffice it to consider the case $k=2$.
2. Name the colors like this: $(r,s)$, where $r$ is one of the $c_1$ colors of graph $H_1$, $s$ is one of the $c_2$ colors of graph $H_2$.
3. How can we paint each vertex of our graph with these colors, knowing what colors the vertices in $H_1$ and $H_2$ had?